# Get 2 rows for each distinct value in column

Tags: java, mysql, postgresql, jdbctemplate

I have a table containing Queue-Items which are periodically (500ms) worked off in a batch of 10.

```
select * from tbl_queue order by prio asc;


----------------------------
 client_id |object_key |prio
----------------------------
1          |4711       | 10
1          |2831       | 10
1          |1912       | 10
1          |1913       | 10
1          |1914       | 10
1          |1915       | 10
1          |1922       | 10
1          |1933       | 10
1          |1944       | 10
1          |1955       | 10
1          |1966       | 10
2          |7861       | 10
2          |1234       | 10
3          |5463       | 10
3          |5464       | 10
4          |7341       | 10
4          |7342       | 10
5          |9425       | 10
5          |9426       | 10
5          |9427       | 10
```

Each time I select from the table I limit the amount I want to work on:

```
select * from tbl_queue order by prio asc limit 10;
```

---

```
 client_id |object_key |prio
----------------------------
1          |4711       | 10
1          |2831       | 10
1          |1912       | 10
1          |1913       | 10
1          |1914       | 10
1          |1915       | 10
1          |1922       | 10
1          |1933       | 10
1          |1944       | 10
1          |1955       | 10
```

However, I would like to treat each client equally, thus my desired result would be:

```
----------------------------
 client_id |object_key |prio
----------------------------    
1          |1913       | 10 
1          |1966       | 10
2          |7861       | 10
2          |1234       | 10
3          |5463       | 10
3          |5464       | 10
4          |7341       | 10
4          |7342       | 10
5          |9425       | 10
5          |9426       | 10
```

Note that I do not care which object_key is chosen. There are two important requirements:

1. if there are items from different clients present, items of each
   client must be selected (preferably equally).
2. the query must always return 10 rows,
   except if there are less than 10 rows.

The proposed solution must work in Mysql and PostgreSQL and it must not be too expensive to insert and select from the table.

I've already thought of adding a column like sort_idx and insert the actual row-count per client in each row, so I'd be able to do this:

```
--------------------------------------
 client_id |object_key |prio| sort_idx
--------------------------------------
1          |4711       | 10 | 1
1          |2831       | 10 | 2
1          |1912       | 10 | 3
1          |1913       | 10 | 4
1          |1914       | 10 | 5
1          |1915       | 10 | 6
1          |1922       | 10 | 7
1          |1933       | 10 | 8 
1          |1944       | 10 | 9
1          |1955       | 10 | 10
1          |1966       | 10 | 11
2          |7861       | 10 | 1
2          |1234       | 10 | 2
3          |5463       | 10 | 1
3          |5464       | 10 | 2
4          |7341       | 10 | 1
4          |7342       | 10 | 2
5          |9425       | 10 | 1
5          |9426       | 10 | 2
5          |9427       | 10 | 3

select * from tbl_queue order by prio, sort_index asc limit 10;

--------------------------------------
 client_id |object_key |prio| sort_idx
--------------------------------------
1          |4711       | 10 | 1
2          |7861       | 10 | 1
3          |5463       | 10 | 1
4          |7341       | 10 | 1
5          |9425       | 10 | 1
1          |2831       | 10 | 2     
2          |1234       | 10 | 2
3          |5464       | 10 | 2
4          |7342       | 10 | 2
5          |9426       | 10 | 2
```

However, I am not too confident about efficiently calculating a sort-index for each insert. There might be situations where 20.000 rows are inserted at once (or in a rapid fashion).

I am not looking for solutions introducing some variables or functions, I neither want to introduce database triggers, just plain sql.

**EDIT 13.09.2017 17:13:** If using user-defined variables is possible within the context of springs' JdbcTemplate I guess it'd be an acceptable solution.

However I'd like to keep things as simple as possible on the database layer (i.e. not use database-specific/exclusive commands)

**EDIT 26.09.2017 11:18**
So I've tested the suggested solution against a real life data set with about 40.000 records and I had to find out that it does not perform well. In fact I canceled query execution after about a minute or so.

An explain on this query gives the following output:

```
explain select c1.client_id,
  c1.object_key,
  c1.prio,
  count(*)-1 as sort_idx
from clients as c1
  left join clients as c2
    on c1.client_id = c2.client_id
      and c1.object_key >= c2.object_key
      and c1.prio >= c2.prio
group by c1.client_id,
        c1.object_key,
        c1.prio
order by
  c1.prio,
  sort_idx
 limit 10;



Limit  (cost=512.53..512.56 rows=10 width=12)
  ->  Sort  (cost=512.53..513.03 rows=200 width=12)
        Sort Key: c1.prio, ((count(*) - 1))
        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=505.71..508.21 rows=200 width=12)
              Group Key: c1.client_id, c1.object_key, c1.prio
              ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.15..484.80 rows=2091 width=12)
                    ->  Seq Scan on clients c1  (cost=0.00..29.40 rows=1940 width=12)
                    ->  Index Only Scan using clients_idx on clients c2  (cost=0.15..0.22 rows=1 width=12)
                          Index Cond: ((client_id = c1.client_id) AND (object_key <= c1.object_key) AND (prio <= c1.prio))
```

I'm not an expert on interpreting explain plans, but whenever the cost-number is high or I see nested loop join I sense danger.

The statement given with the dense rank function works a lot faster, unfortunately I need to support mysql and postgres.

Comment: *I am not looking for solutions introducing some variables* Why not?

Comment: Pardon me for maybe being overly restrictive. We use java and org.​springframework.​jdbc.​core.​JdbcTemplate to read and write to our database. I am not familiar, if using user-defined variables is possible with spring JdbcTemplate. If it is, I guess there should be no reason not to use them. EDIT: I added java and jdbctemplate as keywords

Comment: Presumably java is only concerned with the result which it receives, and not the steps that MySQL takes to construct that result? If so, variables seem like a good idea to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually (MSSQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, etc.) this problem can be solved with the help of DENSE_RANK function.
But since MySQL doesn't have window functions, you can do something like this:

```
select c1.client_id,
  c1.object_key,
  c1.prio,
  count(*)-1 as sort_idx
from clients as c1
  left join clients as c2
    on c1.client_id = c2.client_id
      and c1.object_key >= c2.object_key
      and c1.prio >= c2.prio
group by c1.client_id,
        c1.object_key,
        c1.prio
order by
  c1.prio,
  sort_idx
limit 10;
```

I've made a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/48425/1), you're welcome to test it

**UPDATE:**
Also made a solution for PostgreSQL with DENSE_RANK - just in case someone else wouldn't be restricted with MySQL limitations:

```
select c.client_id,
  c.object_key,
  c.prio,
  DENSE_RANK() OVER   
    (PARTITION BY c.client_id ORDER BY c.object_key) as sort_idx
from clients as c
order by
  c.prio,
  sort_idx
limit 10;
```

And the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/4174a/8)

**UPDATE 2:** 
Made a MySQL-specific solution for `dense_rank` calculation, works much faster than self-join on 40000 records. But it's order-dependent, so you have to use this query result somehow (maybe with the temporary table) to get results ordered by `prio ASC, dense_rank ASC`.

```
SELECT
t2.client_id,
t2.object_key,
t2.prio,
t2.dense_rank
FROM
    (SELECT 
          t1.*,
          @dense:=IF(@prev_client_id=t1.client_id AND @prev_prio=t1.prio, @dense+1, 1) AS dense_rank,
          @prev_client_id:=t1.client_id,
          @prev_prio:=t1.prio
        FROM (select * from clients c1 order by prio, client_id) t1,
             (SELECT @dense:=0, @prev_client_id:=NULL, @prev_prio:=NULL) var1
    ) t2;
```

And the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/beab67/1).

Comment: Nice! Exactly what I was hoping for. I'll have to test it in real world with bigger queue. I guess an index on all the columns in the JOIN-condition/GROUP BY-clause would be advised for better performance?

Comment: @SebastianRiemer, sure it would. Added 'create index' expression to the fiddle.

Comment: I've updated my question - sadly the proposed solution does not perform well. However, I'll stick to accepting your answer since it is the best answer for now.

Comment: I've updated my answer. :) You can use 'custom' MySQL-specific dense_rank to build separate handler for MySQL database. As for PostgreSQL you can use regular DENSE_RANK solution.